# Use python + Selenium to login,but can't find div

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

```
# _*_coding:utf-8_*_
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url="https://login.alibaba.com"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

i want to login by selenium, but can't find the login id "fm-login-id"

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to find the login? Does it throw an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to handle elements inside authentication form, you need to switch to `iframe`:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url="https://login.alibaba.com"
driver.get(url)
deiver.switch_to.frame("alibaba-login-box")
driver.find_element_by_id("fm-login-id").send_keys("my email")
driver.find_element_by_id("fm-login-password").send_keys("my password")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the `URL` you have shared **`url="https://login.alibaba.com"`**, to locate the `Email Address` field i.e **fm-login-id** through **`Selenium-Java`** you can use either of the following :

- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='fm-login-id']")
  ```
- **`cssSelector`** :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#fm-login-id")
  ```

Comment: Corrected my `Java` styled `xpath` and `css_selector` to `Python` style.

Answer (score 0):

Alibaba's login is in different iFrame that's why you are not getting its id and got the error "**Element not found**"

I created one sample for you in java selenium and it's working.

```
driver.get("https://passport.alibaba.com/mini_login.htm?lang=en_us&appName=icbu&appEntrance=default&styleType=auto&bizParams=&notLoadSsoView=false&notKeepLogin=true&isMobile=false&ut=B8605a4b80fd5c7e8e8957efccc7ad5ea&showKeepLogin=true&showSnsLogin=true&cssLink=https%3A%2F%2Fu.alicdn.com%2Fcss%2F6v%2Frun%2Fcommon%2Fxman%2Fhavana-thirdpart-login.css&regUrl=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.alibaba.com%2Fregister%2Fregister.htm%3Freturn_url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.alibaba.com&rnd=0.2729010632370805");              
        Thread.sleep(3);        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='fm-login-id']")).sendKeys("Test_User");
```

I ran this code and and it's working fine.

Comment: If my answer helps you or solved your error then please mark (✔) as a answer.